# XML language is backed or front end?

Tags: xml

Might be the question is silly, but i don't have any tutor to answer.
so i posted here.

I know XML is backed language . but in android XML is using as a front end language. please tell me is it possible that we can change the front\back end as per our coding language.

and also please share some books for developing a knowledge in java for android

please clarify

Comment: There is no such thing as a front end or back end language. There may be front end or back end implementations. But data languages such as XML and JSON, to be useful, always have both. One of their main purposes, after all, is for communication between the front and back ends.

Comment: ok thanks , it's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

XML is just a self-describing language - that's easy for machines as well as humans to read, so for example

```
<page>
    <button text="press me"/>
</page>
```

is valid XML and can be used to describe a user interface (like HTML or Xaml) or data stored in the back end of a service like this

```
<books> 
    <book title="Catch 22"/>
</books>
```

It's all in how you use it.  Different software platforms use it in different ways.

Comment: so we cant predict into particular language like front\back end.??

Comment: I don't understand your question.  XML is just a text format.

Answer (score 0):

Extensible Mark-up Language is a mark-up language much like HTML.

XML was designed to store and transport data so in a sense it’s neither frontend nor backend much like HTML.

For example, the backend can generate HTML which is passed to the frontend for rendering a webpage.

XML can be generated by the backend and passed to the frontend for displaying information. And by the same account the frontend can generate XML data to be passed to the backend for storing/processing.

**Example:**

Here we have an XML for storing information about books. This could be generated by the backend and passed to the frontend.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

At this point the frontend might parse this data and extract only the book author and title; displaying something like:

> Author: Gambardella, Matthew
> Title: XML Developer's Guide

> Author: Ralls, Kim
> Title: Midnight Rain